# In a mobile browser, how do I sign in to a different Google account without adding it to an existing account?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I was struggling with this on my iPhone today.  I have two browsers, Chrome and the built-in Safari.

My wife signed in to her Gmail account Safari, and I signed in to my (Google-based) work email account in Chrome.  There doesn't appear to be any option to completely log out in either case.

[image: Initial screen]

---

**When I tap on the "Sign in with a different account" link, I get this:**

[image: Second screen]

There's simply no option to sign out and sign in with another account.  Is this by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you sign out of your account then do the following:

1. click on add account
2. then click on remove
3. click on cross mark of the existing account and done button
4. again press done button
5. Now you are out of your previous logged account
6. At this stage the page redirects to a new page in which you can sign in to a new account

Answer (score 1):

If you click to sign in with another account then you can delete the login, but short of blocking the cookie there doesn't seem to be anything to actually stop it from remembering.

This is a huge issue for us who offer training and have different people signing in too and must be really annoying for Internet cafes!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you can use the privacy mode, so the account will not conflict. :)

When using "Private Browsing", the websites you visited will not leave a search history in Safari.